# How do you match line numbers from a Stack Trace to source code?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

I've never quite understood how the line numbers from a Stack Trace are supposed to line up to the original source code. The Stack Trace usually ends with something like

C:\Path\Source.cs:line 123

However, the line number is often off by quite a bit. Does anyone know how to properly match the line numbers to those of the original source code?

Comment: *However, the line number is often off by quite a bit* .. NO, not per my experience unless some modification in source code went through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack traces from release builds may be different from the source code since the compiler may optimize the code, remove lines, or even inline whole methods. In debug builds most optimizations are turned of and the stack traces should be more accurate.

One approach to handle this would be to validate parameters at the start of methods and throw appropriate exceptions, and include necessary details in the message to better get an idea what went wrong.

edit:
Also check that the pdb files matches both the source and the dlls. The pdb files contain the mapping from IL-code to source code, so is required for line-numbers in the stack traces.

Answer (score -1):

> However, the line number is often off by quite a bit.

No, it is not. IF it is - you made changes to the source code. OBVIOUSLY the line number refers to the COMPILED source code, not the current one. Basically: use a version control system and number your versions. They do line up.